Streaming chat response in flatlist
I'm building a mobile app with an integrated chat that uses OpenAI API or llama3 as model. i managed to get the streaming working properly. However I have a small problem when display the message being streamed. currently the message is displayed once the streaming is done instead of having a Chatgpt or any other LLM experience where you get message by chunk. here's my current code.
Chat.tsx
  const {
    messages,
    addMessage,
    removeMessage,
    updateMessage,
    setIsMessageUpdating,
  } = useContext(MessagesContext);

 <FlatList
          data={messages}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View
              style={styles.messageContainer}
              className={cn("flex justify-end", {
                "items-end": item.isUserMessage,
              })}
            >
              <View
                className={cn(
                  "flex flex-row gap-y-2 text-sm max-w-[90%] mx-2 overflow-x-hidden"
                )}
              >
                <View
                  className={cn("px-4 py-2 rounded-lg", {
                    "bg-primary ": item.isUserMessage,
                    "bg-secondary ": !item.isUserMessage,
                  })}
                >
                  <Text
                    className={cn({
                      "text-white ": item.isUserMessage,
                    })}
                  >
                    {item.text}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.messagesList}
        />

Here's my function to handle the message sent with react query
  const { mutate: sendMessage, isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ["sendMessage"],
    // include message to later use it in onMutate
    mutationFn: async (message: Message) => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/mobile/virtual-coach`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ messages }),
        }
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }

      return response.body;
    },
    onMutate(message) {
      addMessage(message);
    },
    onSuccess: async (stream) => {
      if (!stream) throw new Error("No stream");

      // // construct new message to add
      const id = customAlphabet(
        "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        10
      )();

      const responseMessage = {
        id,
        isUserMessage: false,
        text: "",
      };
      // add new message to state
      addMessage(responseMessage);
      setIsMessageUpdating(true);
      const reader = stream.getReader();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
      let done = false;

      while (!done) {
        const { value, done: doneReading } = await reader.read();
        done = doneReading;
        const chunkValue = decoder.decode(new Uint8Array([value]), {
          stream: true,
        });
        updateMessage(id, (prev) => prev + chunkValue);
      }

      // // clean up
      setIsMessageUpdating(false);
    
    },
    onError: (_, message) => {
      console.log("error", _);
      removeMessage(message.id);
    },
  });

I think it has to do with flatlist re-redering behavior.

I think it has to do with the fetch library react native is built with. It doesnt support streaming, so instead of sending chunks as received it waits for response to end

I havent tried it, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-api?activeTab=readme claims to support text streaming

You're right. it has to do with the fetch library. despite using the react native fetch API I'm still having that problem. i tried using a static text and iterating over it to simulate a streaming like behavior and it worked properly.
